# MySQL Syntax Error on Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near = -1 else SELECT audit_id INTO t_new_id FROM a_audit_reg at line 11



delimiter //
CREATE  FUNCTION get_audit_id (p_pubco_id int(10),
                              p_audit_id int(10),
                              p_fiscal_date date) 
       RETURNS int(10) 
BEGIN 

   DECLARE t_new_id int(10);

#check paremeters here
if p_pubco_id = 0 or p_audit_id = 0
then set t_new_id = -1
else
   set t_new_id = (SELECT audit_id
     FROM a_audit_reg 
    WHERE p_pubco_id = a_audit_reg.pubco_id
      and p_audit_id = a_audit_reg.audit_id
      and p_fiscal_period = a_audit_reg.fiscal_period_date);

   if found_rows() = 0
   then
        insert into a_audit_reg (pubco_id, audit_id, fiscal_period_date)
               values (p_pubco_id, p_audit_id, p_fiscal_date);
        set t_new_id = last_insert_id();
   end if;
end if;
   return t_new_id;

END //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I've fixed the delimiter, but now I get this error, here it in full. `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= -1 else SELECT audit_id INTO t_new_id FROM a_audit_reg ' at line 11`

Comment: you need to use `SET`, see below.

Comment: thank you so much, I updated the code above to show you what I have used and as you can see, I had used `SET`. The problem was no semi-colon after the -1. Thanks again for your help mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- change the `DELIMITER`
- use `SET`

query,

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE  FUNCTION get_audit_id
(
    p_pubco_id INT, 
    p_audit_id INT, 
    p_fiscal_date DATE
) 
RETURNS INT
BEGIN 
    DECLARE t_new_id INT;

    IF p_pubco_id = 0 or p_audit_id = 0 THEN    
        SET t_new_id = -1;
    ELSE
        SET t_new_id = (SELECT audit_id
                        FROM a_audit_reg 
                        WHERE p_pubco_id = a_audit_reg.pubco_id
                            and p_audit_id = a_audit_reg.audit_id
                            and p_fiscal_period = a_audit_reg.fiscal_period_date);

        IF found_rows() = 0 then
            insert into a_audit_reg (pubco_id, audit_id, fiscal_period_date)
            values (p_pubco_id, p_audit_id, p_fiscal_date);

            SET t_new_id = last_insert_id();
        end if;
    end if;
    return t_new_id;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this worked great, thanks. but now I have another! error, error soup. `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'else set t_new_id = (SELECT audit_id FROM a_audit_reg WHERE p' at line 12`

Comment: then you try to run the code above? may be you lack `;` after this statement `SET t_new_id = -1`.